# xml response not picking nested @XmlRootElement(name="Cans")

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I am trying to get a response of XML. The root XML is nested inside an XML element. when the response comes out the root element never comes from the response, here is my attempt.

I am trying to get this -

```
<Cans>  
    <Can>
    <Name>bla bla</Name>
    <Size>10</Size>
    <Can>   
    </Cans>
```

but response keeps coming as this -

```
<Cans>  
    <Name>bla bla</Name>
    <Size>10</Size> 
    </Cans>
```

below is my structure to achieve the desired result

```
//in the drink class
    
    .....
    
    private Cans cans; //this is a class referenced here
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Cans")
    public Cans getCans() {
        return cans;
    }

    public void setCans(Cans cans) {
        this.cans = cans;
    }
    
    //cans class
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
    @XmlRootElement(name="Can")
    public class Cans implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    .....
```

Please how can I achieve the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

The class `Cans` has two XmlElements associated, `Can` and `Cans`, so when you call `getCans()` it's using the method defined `@XmlElement(name = "Cans")`.

You should associate `@XmlElement(name = "Can")` with the class and use a list of Can to associate with `@XmlElement(name = "Cans")`